# Slanted box in CHROME

Tags: css, google-chrome

Bevelled edge looks bad in Chrome. In Firefox is ok. Why?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaxJKv

```
.rr-left:after {
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid #2c3e50;
    border-right: 1050px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Subpixel rendering and/or rounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the border top to RGBA(44, 62, 80, 0).  This smooths the line a fair bit:

```
border-top: 30px solid rgba(44, 62, 80, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmvq5uz1/